# Skype for Business Online Web SDK SignIn Lync Autodiscover Unauthorized

Tags: office365, office365api, lync-client-sdk, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to integrate Skype for Business into my current AngularJS web application. I've followed the steps at https ://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt622687(v=office.16).aspx and am unable to sign in.

I believe my app is properly registered on Azure AD since I've previously integrated Outlook (O365) into my application which had the same requirements.

So, I authenticate the user with Office 365 Online via *adalAuthenticationServiceProvider* using the following initialization (examples below masks portions of tenant and clientId):

```
var endpoints = {
        'https://outlook.office365.com': 'https://outlook.office365.com',
        'https://webdir.online.lync.com': 'https://webdir.online.lync.com'
    };

    // Initialize the ADAL provider with your tenant name and clientID (found in the Azure Management Portal).
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
        {
            tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx1.onmicrosoft.com',
            clientId: '8720xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe2a3a20c',
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost/defaultDashboard',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost/defaultDashboard',
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            anonymousEndpoints: ["/"],
            endpoints: endpoints
        },
        $httpProvider
    );
```

Then, I try to sign in to Skype for Business Online followed by an attempt to sign in a user using the access token received from Azure AD that is stored within our *adalAuthenticationService*:

```
    var config = {
        apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
        apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
    };

    Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
        var app = new api.application;

        app.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
            console.log("Login State: " + state);
        });

        app.signInManager.signIn({
            "client_id": "8720xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe2a3a20c",  //GUID obtained from Azure app registration.
            "origins": ["https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root"],
            "cors": true,
            "redirect_uri": 'http://localhost/defaultDashboard', // Can be any location in the current site. (Any valid Url)
            "version": 'xxxxx/1.0.0.0'
            });

        var resource = adalAuthenticationService.getResourceForEndpoint('localhost');
        var tokenStored = adalAuthenticationService.getCachedToken(resource);

        if (tokenStored) {
            var Bearercwt = 'Bearer cwt=';
            var Bearer = 'Bearer ';
            var cwt = 'cwt';

            if (tokenStored.indexOf(cwt) == -1) {
                tokenStored = Bearercwt + tokenStored;
            }
            if (tokenStored.indexOf(Bearer) == -1) {
                tokenStored = Bearer + tokenStored;
            }

            var options = {
                auth: function (req, send) {
                    req.headers['Authorization'] = tokenStored.trim();
                    return send(req);
                },
                domain: 'localhost'
            };

            app.signInManager.signIn(options).then(
                function () {
                    console.log('Signed in as ' + app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.name());
                },
                function(err) {
                    console.log('Sign in failed: '+err);
                });
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err.toString());
    });
```

I would first like to note that I am unclear as to why the *Development Doc* suggests two seperate *signInManager.signIn* calls. My real problem, however, is that the first *signIn* call (using the clientId) triggers a GET call that is refused due to "Invalid Credentials" (see below).

[webdirca1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user : 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CazGP.png)

Afterwards, this same call gets triggered in a loop every ~3 seconds, this time returning a "Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin" error (see below).

[webdirca1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user : 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz0K3.png)

If I comment out the first *signIn* call and attempt to sign in using only the access token received from the Azure AD authentication, I am faced with two net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR lyncdiscover errors from https ://lyncdiscoverinternal.localhost/xframe and https ://lyncdiscover.localhost/xframe respectively (see below; P.S. I get the same error if I change the domain from localhost to my Azure AD tenant).

Am I missing any prerequisites for developing web SDK applications for Skype for Business Online? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Here is the Skype Wed SDK for Skype for Business Online Development Doc link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt622687(v=office.16).aspx (new Stackoverflow user here, couldn't post more than two links, sorry).

Comment: Why are you logging in via ADAL before Skype for Business?  The reason for the two calls to the signInManager is to handle two concerns: (1) authenticating to Azure AD and (2) using those credentials to authenticate to Skype for Business.

Are you certain that 'http://localhost/defaultDashboard' directs to a valid location in your site?

Comment: I'm using ADAL to authenticate to Azure AD in order to access Office 365 Outlook (this is working). 

So if signInManager call (1) is simply to authenticate and retrieve credentials, I could technically just use the credentials retrieved from the ADAL authentication for call (2), right? 

And yes 'localhost/defaultDashboard' directs to a valid location, notice how I use it in the "adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init" function under "redirectUri" and it redirects as expected upon proper authentication (via ADAL).

Comment: I'd think the answer would be maybe as I don't have all the same pieces are you have access to.  Typically step 1 is calling to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=$client_id&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri which might mean you are authenticating to a different resource than what is required for Skype for Business.  I would say give it a try and skip step 1 and see if you can skip it since the cookie should be present.

Answer (score 0):

The second signin with option containing **domain: 'localhost'** is not required as its only used for skype for bussiness on premise case.

Please find modified code. It might work for you.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
    apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
};

Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
    var app = new api.application;

    app.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
        console.log("Login State: " + state);
    });


    var resource = adalAuthenticationService.getResourceForEndpoint('localhost');
    var tokenStored = adalAuthenticationService.getCachedToken(resource);

    if (tokenStored) {
        var Bearercwt = 'Bearer cwt=';
        var Bearer = 'Bearer ';
        var cwt = 'cwt';

        if (tokenStored.indexOf(cwt) == -1) {
            tokenStored = Bearercwt + tokenStored;
        }
        if (tokenStored.indexOf(Bearer) == -1) {
            tokenStored = Bearer + tokenStored;
        }

        var options = {
            "client_id": "8720xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe2a3a20c",  //GUID obtained from Azure app registration.
            "origins": ["https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root"],
            "cors": true,
            "redirect_uri": 'http://localhost/defaultDashboard', // Can be any location in the current site. (Any valid Url)
            "version": 'xxxxx/1.0.0.0'
        };

        app.signInManager.signIn(options).then(
            function () {
                console.log('Signed in as ' + app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.name());
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log('Sign in failed: '+err);
            });
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err.toString());
});
```